# Query current user .once('value') in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am transitioning a Firebase real-time database to a Firebase Firestore database but am having trouble finding the appropriate reference to query the current user.

```
onAuthUserListener = (next, fallback) =>
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
  if (authUser) {
    this.user(authUser.uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const dbUser = snapshot.val();

        // default empty roles
        if (!dbUser.roles) {
          dbUser.roles = [];
        }

        // merge auth and db user
        authUser = {
          uid: authUser.uid,
          email: authUser.email,
          emailVerified: authUser.emailVerified,
          providerData: authUser.providerData,
          ...dbUser,
        };

        next(authUser);
      });
  } else {
    fallback();
  }
});
```

Most specifically, what would be the replacement for `once('value')` and `snapshot.val();`?

I had thought that

```
.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  const dbUser = snapshot.val();
  ...
```

Comment: Answer on the equivalent of `once('value'` is below, but I have no idea what `   this.user(authUser.uid)` is.

Comment: Thank you Frank. ` this.user(authUser.uid)` is just my way of accessing the plugin via `context`. Cheers for your answer, I'll give it a go now.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem as you. Did you figure this out? I'm not smart enough to be able to make the leap from the firebase documentation to writing something that works to get a user from firestore that has the same uid as authUser in the Authentication context. Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `once('value'` in Firestore is called `get()`, and the equivalent of `val()` is `data()`. Calling `get()` returns a promise, so:

```
.get().then(snapshot => {
  const dbUser = snapshot.data();
  ...
```

If you have a collection of users, where the profile of each user is stored within a document with their UID as its ID, you can load that with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(authUser.uid)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    const dbUser = snapshot.val();
```

Note that this is pretty well covered in the [documentation on getting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), so I'd recommend spending some time there and potentially taking the [Cloud Firestore codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web/).

Comment: I tried this but there was no .then() method directly in .doc(uid).get(). As said in https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1413#issuecomment-356352970, you have to get a ref object like this: firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid).ref.get().then( ... );

Comment: This question was not related to AngularFire, while the link you provide is very specific to that library. If you're having a problem calling the `then` method, I suggest you open a new question and add the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).